# Let $f(x)$ be a function on $(-\infty, \infty)$ and $f(x+2)=f(x-2)$. Find number of roots of $f(x)=0$ in $(-8,10]$ with given condtion

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

> > Let $f(x)$ be a function on $(-\infty, \infty)$ and $f(x+2)=f(x-2)$. If $f(x)=0$ has only three real roots in $[0,4]$ and one of them is $4$, then the number of real roots of $f(x)=0$ in $(-8,10]$ is

**My Solution:**

$f(x+2)=f(x-2)$

Replace $x$ by $x+2$ in given functional equation

Hence I obtained $f(x+4)=f(x)\implies$ $f(x)$ is periodic with period $4$

Since $f(x)=0$ has $3$ real roots in $[0,4]$

It is given that $f(4)=0\implies f(0)=f(4)=0$
and one roots in between $[0,4]$

$\implies$ in interval $(-8,10]$ it can have either $8$ or $9$ real roots.

**But given answer is $9$ and reasoning given is that $f(x)=\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi x}{2}\right)$  satisfies all condition. Author of book is considering $f(2)=0$ but How can he be sure that $f(2)=0$**

Comment: You are right and the book is wrong : the function has $8$ or $9$ real roots, depending on if the unknown root in $[0,4]$ is $\leq 2$ or $>2$.

Comment: $f(2)$ need not be $0$. Given any $t \in (0,4)$ there exists a periodic function $f$ with period $4$ such that its only roots in $[0,4]$ are $0,t $ and $4$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Differential calculus by Amit M. Agrawal. Page number $153$. I will add Image for the same

Comment: I just checked the book, and it is indeed very false : it says basically that since $\sin(\pi x/2)$ satisfies the conditions of the question, then $f$ must be of that form !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument given by the author is obviously false. Here's a screenshot of the answer (the [book](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NaIdTl7LJEjo64K9yS-2zPrtXdrhwS31/view), titled "Differential Calculus with Sessionwise theory and exercises" by Amit M.Agarwal. The exercise is option (a),Ex. 25 (Match the following), page 153) :

$\hspace{3cm}$ [image]

The author is correct, until the part where they claim that $f$ has only $3$ roots in $[0,4]$ (and also mentions that $x=0$ and $x=4$ are two of those roots).

The next line is as baffling as it is wrong. It is true that $\sin\frac{\pi x}{2}$ is a function satisfying the periodicity condition and having roots at those places, but it's definitely not the only one.

I can understand what makes the author gravitate towards the sine function : it's the most obvious periodic function that is taught at this level. However, there are tons and tons of other functions which are periodic. I mean, there's no insistence on $f$ being continuous.

You could literally take something like this : for every $t \in (0,4)$, define $f_t : [0,4) \to \mathbb R$ by $f_t(0) = f_t(t) = 0$ and $f_t(x) = 1$ for every $x \neq t$. Then extend $f$ periodically by letting $f(x) = f(x')$, where $x'$ is the unique element in $[0,4)$ such that $x-x'$ is an integer multiple of $4$.

For example, $f_1(x)$ will be zero at all integers which leave a remainder of $0$ or $1$ when divided by $4$, and will be $1$ at all other points. This will have $9$ roots in the interval $(-8,10]$ given by $-7,-4,-3,0,1,4,5,8,9$.

However, if you take $f_3(x)$, then this will be zero at all integers which leave a remainder of $0$ or $3$ when divided by $4$, and will be $1$ at all other points. This will have $\mathbf{8}$ roots in $(-8,10]$ given by $-5,-4,-1,0,3,4,7,8$.

It is easy to see that every function $f(x)$ must have at least $8$ roots in $(-8,10]$ and must have at most $9$ roots. (For what it's worth, ChatGPT got this right first time, which shows how easy it is) In the interval $[0,4]$, $f$ has three roots, $0,4$ and $0<t<4$. Then, four roots of $f$ are given by $-4,0,4,8$. One easily checks that, given any $t \in (0,4)$, each of $t-8,t-4,t,t+4 \in (-8,10]$, so that's at least $8$ roots. On the other hand, $t-4k \notin (-8,10]$ for $k \geq 3$, and $t+4k \notin (-8,10]$ for $k \geq 3$, but $t+8 \in (-8,10]$ may happen or not depending on the value of $t$, showing that $f$ may have $8$ or $9$ roots in $(-8,10]$ depending on the value of $t$.

---

Observe that what *may have* led the author to this erroneous thinking is that the question is actually part of a "match the following" set : so that if the other options are matched, then the answer of $9$ is forced as a unique match for this question and the author may have tried to force their way through to it. The other options have solutions that are correct and uncontroversial (including the one whose answer is $8$, the other possible answer to our question above).

It's important to point out this error for two reasons : it shows the "right" kind of substitution that must be made to solve these questions, and this is a pretty popular book as far as I know, so it's nice to have a confirmed error logged on here with the clarification.